# Difference between arr pointer and arr notation

Tags: c, pointers

What are the differences between  (in C)

```
int * a
int [] a;
```

Where suppose we did `int * a = malloc(...)`

Isn't the second one also a pointer?

Comment: No, it's not. It can decay to one, but it's a different type.

Comment: The biggest difference is that one of them is valid, while the other one is not.

Comment: what is apache POI doing in this question?

Comment: The second one is a syntax error

Comment: I suggest you read section 6 of the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: No, arrays are not pointers. Likewise, a street is not the address of a house, a bunch of flowers is not the vase you put them in, and the people lining up to buy the newest phone are not the entrance to the store that sells phones.

Comment: The second line is not even valid C.

Comment: Even if the second line is `int a[];` it would still be an error (unless a `struct` member).

Answer (score 0):

As it stands right now, the second is simply a syntax error. The closest you could do would be `int a[];` Even that, however, it's allowed--for a variable definition, the brackets need to contain a constant expression with a strictly positive value.

For a function parameter, `int a[]` would be allowed, and so would something like `int a[3]`. In this case, the two are precisely equivalent--when you define a function parameter with a type `array of T`, it is adjusted to a type `pointer to T`.

You can also do an *extern* declaration:

```
extern int *a;
extern int b[];
```

In this case, the two are actually both syntactically valid, but the results are different--you're declaring that `a` has type `pointer to int`, while `b` has type `array of int`.

If you evaluate the name of an array in an expression, it will usually yield the address of the first element of that array (though there are a few exceptions, such as when used as the argument to `sizeof`). The array itself doesn't have that type though--what you're looking at is at least similar to an implicit conversion, somewhat similar to `2 + 10.0`, converting the `2` to a `double` before doing the addition--`2` itself is an `int`, but in this expression, it's silently converted to `double`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the difference between the following declarations

```
int a[N];
```

and

```
int *a = malloc( N * sizeof( int ) );
```

where `N` is some integer value.

The first one declares an array with the static or automatic storage duration. The second one does two things. Its initializing expression allocates dynamically memory that can be occupied by an array with `N` elements of type `int`. And the address of the extent of memory is assigned to the pointer `a`.
The allocated memory should be freed by the user when it is not needed any more.

So in the first declaration there is declared an object of type `int[N]` while in the second declaration there is declared an object of type `int *`. Correspondingly the size of the first object is equal to `sizeof( int[N] )` that is equivalent to `N * sizeof( int )` while the size of the second object is equal to `sizeof( int * )`.

Pointers do not possess the information about whether they point to a single object or the first object of an array. So the user should hold the number of elements of the allocated array himself while for an array it can get the number by using expression `sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a )`.